# Mapping problem with tidyverse, sf & tmap

Tags: r

I am having a strange issue (which i think has only arisen recently) when I am trying to plot some regional data I have manipulated with tidyverse & sf. I am using tmap to plot. So I select and summarise Mexican & US regions, the polygons are plotting fine + colours, but my code doesn't seem to drop the country names (ADM0_NAME), they are all list from the original dataset.

```
gual$area <- st_area(gual)
gual_us_mex_new <-
  gual %>% 
  dplyr::select(ADM0_CODE, ADM0_NAME, ADM1_NAME, ADM1_CODE, area) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(ADM0_NAME == "Mexico" | ADM0_NAME ==  "United States of America") %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!ADM1_NAME == "Alaska" & !ADM1_NAME ==  "Hawaii") %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(ADM0_CODE, ADM0_NAME, ADM1_NAME, ADM1_CODE)  %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(area = sum(area, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()

library(tmap)

tm_shape(gual_us_mex_new) +
  tm_polygons("ADM0_NAME")
```

result
[image]

Comment: I can only guess its a `factor` and the levels aren't being dropped. Its  guess because we don't have your data or code to confirm. Either convert factors to character before doing this or drop the levels (using `droplevels`) after filtering.

Comment: great thanks so much,  using droplevels worked a treat!